# Can't understand MVC example code given by EXT JS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I am going through the Example on MVC and  i don't understand the following

1.) I didnt understand what `itemdblclick` means ? I know it means double clicks and when we d-click on the grid the function coresponding to it gets executed, but i don't think this is a pre-difined function. So from where does it come from. Imagine there is a button and i want it to log a message to the console saying it was clicked (as shown below) what will  `itemdblclick` be ?

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: [
        'user.List'
    ],

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'userlist': {
                itemdblclick: this.editUser
            }
        });
    },

    editUser: function(grid, record) {
        console.log('Double clicked on ' + record.get('name'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemdblclick` is the name of event. You look for events supported by the control you're working with. For example for button it will be here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button

And then specify event you're subscribing to.

Comment: Thank you, and say i want to get the popup window displayed when i D-Clicked on the Column of the Grid how should i write the control statement. `'userlist > ???': {...` (Something like this) , but how can i get the ID of that Column ?

Answer (score 1):

In the this.control block, you are setting up event listeners.  So itemdblclick is an event name that is fired by the userlist control.

Comment: Thank you, and say i want to get the popup window displayed when i D-Clicked on the Column of the Grid how should i write the control statement. 'userlist > ???': {... (Something like this) , but how can i get the ID of that Column ?